# How to insert a column to a .txt file in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a text file as:

```
0   0   0   0   2   3   2

15  9   0   0   1   20

17  9   0   0   1   17

16  0   0   6   1   10

13  0   0   9   1   12

17  0   0   3   2   21  19

12  0   4   0   2   16  15

12  0   0   1   2   11  16
```

I want to add a column to number these rows as:

```
1   0   0   0   0   2   3   2

2   15  9   0   0   1   20

3   17  9   0   0   1   17

4   16  0   0   6   1   10

5   13  0   0   9   1   12

6   17  0   0   3   2   21  19

7   12  0   4   0   2   16  15

8   12  0   0   1   2   11  16
```

How may I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rewrite the file:

```
List<string> newLines = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select((l, index) => String.Format("{0}   {1}", index + 1, l))
    .ToList();
File.WriteAllLines(path, newLines);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, get all the lines of the text file as so.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
```

And then create a string variable to put the new text into and add the column.

```
string output = "";
for(int i = 1; i <= lines.Length; i++)
{
    output+=i+"\t"+lines[i-1];
    if (i < lines.Length)
    {
        output+="\n";
    }
}
```

And then save the text back to the file.

```
File.WriteAllText(file,output);
```